# What is difference between the agent in Jenkins pipeline and other CD(continuous delivery )tools like ArgoCD etc?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd, argocd

This must be very basic but as i am very new to this and in phase of learning, I have one confusion that what is the difference between the agent we are using in Jenkins pipeline like (docker, none and any) and ArgoCD..? as both of them serve the same purpose of deploying what is written in jenkins file to docker containers.. is agent also considered in CD part i.e. continuous delivery in pipelines?

I have tried deploying a jenkins pipeline and used docker as agent and then i was about to try one more pipeline but got to know about ArgoCD so this confusion popped up in mind.

Hope to get answers for easy understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is a general-purpose automation server that supports building, testing, and deploying applications across various environments.
While ArgoCD is focused on continuous delivery for Kubernetes applications. It uses GitOps principles to manage the state of applications in a Kubernetes cluster.